# ToDouble returns wrong number

Tags: c#, double

I have a string, `"999999999999.999"`. I want to convert it to a `double`. I tried a lot of things but it always returns me the wrong number.

I tried:

```
Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDouble("999999999999.999") * 1000) / 1000;
```

It returns me: `99999999999.99902`

Only `Convert.ToDouble("999999999999.999")` returns me the same.

The `02` part is the wrong part.

How can I convert the string `"999999999999.999"` to a `double` without losing precision or accuracy?

Comment: It returns me 99999999999.99902 But i need 999999999999.999

Comment: is it always just three decimal digits?

Comment: Yes, i need maximum three decimal digits

Comment: is decimal acceptable?  sounds like it may be a better data type for you than double

Comment: Writing numbers as decimals, then expecting the conversion to what is a binary floating point representation is flawed. If you need decimal like behaviour, then use the `decimal` type.

Comment: I don't understind!! if you convert `string str = "999999999999.999"; ` to double like this : `double d = Convert.ToDouble(str);` the result is 999999999999.999

Comment: #Abdellah OUMGHAR Yes it should be, but instead of 999999999999.999, it returns me 99999999999.99902

Comment: Try this : `(Convert.ToDouble("999999999999.999")-999999999999)`  vs this : `(Convert.ToDouble("9.999")-9)`, and you'll start to see why your choice of numeric type is unsuited to what you're trying to achieve. You're progressively losing more precision with bigger numbers. `decimal` is your friend.

Comment: spender you are right, absolutely, ToDecimal returns me the right number. But it is declared as double in the database, I meen it is declared as NUMBER(12,3). The ORM generator generates it as double, i cant use decimal :(

Comment: Do you really need the precision you are demanding?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the exact precision convert it to decimal

While converting to double there will be a precision loss

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional information that there will be no more than 12 digits before the decimal point and 3 after, double should be precise enough to distinguish all the numbers you can store.

For example, the largest number is represented by 999999999999.9990234375, which is closer to 999999999999.999 than to any other three decimal place number.

You will need to control the formatting so that you round to the nearest 3 decimal place number.

If you do any calculations, you should convert to Decimal, rounding to 3 decimal places, to avoid accumulating rounding error.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
double aux = double.Parse("999999999999.999") * 1000 / 1000;
double result = Math.Round(aux, 3);
```

Comment: This isn't c# and it doesn't compile.

Comment: Had to open VS and see what was the problem hahaha, tested it myself now

Comment: The closest 64-bit IEEE 754 binary float to 999999999999.999 is 999999999999.9990234375. No amount of multiplications, divisions, or rounding can get any closer.